# What is needed ONLY for Twitter Bootstrap's Popover?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I understand I can go to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#components and select the only the components I need to make the popovers work.

I updated the `js` and `css` to link to the files downloaded.  I'm not getting any errors but I'm also not getting the popover.

**Original Question:**
I'd like to add the popover to my site but the bootstrap's standard css file conflicts with my existing styling.  From http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css, can someone tell me which bits and pieces I need just for the popovers?  I used Firebug to see what classes are called but I'm obviously missing something.  I don't have to use Boostrap's Popover, I'm open to other plugins if they are as easy to use.

CSS

```
/* CSS Document */
.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1010;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
.popover.top {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.popover.right {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.popover.bottom {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.popover.left {
  margin-left: -5px;
}
.popover.top .arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #000000;
}
.popover.right .arrow {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #000000;
}
.popover.bottom .arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;
}
.popover.left .arrow {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #000000;
}
.popover .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.popover-inner {
  padding: 3px;
  width: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.popover-title {
  padding: 9px 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.popover-content {
  padding: 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.popover-content p, .popover-content ul, .popover-content ol {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade.in {
  opacity: 1;
}

h3 {
  /*    line-height: 27px;  */
  font-size: 18px;
}

p {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 0 0 9px;
}
```

Comment: The CSS above is what I determined I needed if that wasn't clear.

Comment: So make YOUR styles more specific, which is always a good idea anyway, and they will override.

Comment: Just look at the [source code](https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/master/less/popovers.less). You'd have to write your own `.border-radius()` function and add in the proper variables.

Comment: The site is an 8 year old site and we have been asked to make it more current looking.  The site is too large to redo existing css just for a silly popover but the client really wants it so who knows. :)

Comment: George edited my question removing the components I downloaded so I'm adding them here.  I felt it is good to know what I downloaded in hopes some else can tell me what I missed or did not need:

I downloaded: 1) Choose Components JS Components ToolTips Popovers     2) Select jQuery plugins Tooltips Popovers (requires Tooltips) - because of this, is why I also selected toptips under section 1 above).    3) Customize Variables I left this as-is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customize your download right on the twitter bootstrap site ([here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)). In order to get the css just for the popover just select that and uncheck everything else, that you will allow you to download both the regular and responsive classes used on the popover alone.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but when I went back and tried again, I was able to get it to work.

Comment: @dlackey Cache issues maybe? Sometimes all it takes is a refresh. Although i suggest you go through the customized download route, since that way you will acquire all required classes (even those used by the javascript plugins for the effects).

Comment: There is no css for popovers or tooltips only! http://getbootstrap.com/customize/